# some javascript codes make me can't open the devTools on chrome

Tags: javascript

There is a website's page has this code which dissallows me open the chrome console panel:

```js
var element = new Image();
Object.defineProperty(element, 'id', {
  get: function(){ window.location.href = "/about" }
});
console.log(element);
```

My chrome browser has installed chrome extension "shortkeys" which can run a javascript code on a fully loaded page and I try to use this extension to run a javascript code for modifying the var element, so the page does not redirect to the page `/about` when I press the key of <kbd>F12</kbd>.

To make the `element = null` will not work. Please tell me what I can do to go through it, thanks.

Comment: This code is a bit strange. It defines `id` property for `element` and when we are trying to get its value we are redirected to `/about`. Is the code correct?

Comment: @Ivan Didyk  this strange code is to prevent opening the devTools, that's the purpose!

Comment: Maybe, `console.clear()` will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

#### How is this working?

1. Your code is defining the getter for `element.id`. If you will try to get `id`, you will be redirected to `/about`
2. Code logs element to console.
3. When you open console, Chrome gets values of all props of `element` (including computed `id`)
4. When Chrome is attempting to get value for `id`, JS redirects to another page

#### How can I avoid this?

You could use `console.clear()`. It will remove ALL messages from console and when getter for `id` will not be invoked.

#### Why was `element = null` not working?

Because there was created a copy of `element` on log. Further modifications are not affecting the copy.